# Linq + Single line condition

Tags: c#, linq, conditional-statements

Here is a piece of code:

```
var test = myListOfItems.Select(x => MyMethodReturningObject(x.SubItems) != null ? theValue : x.SubItems[0])
```

I would like that if MyMethodReturningObject returns an object, I assign the return value to theValue.

A bit like this:

```
var test = myListOfItems.Select(x => MyFunctionReturningObject(x.SubItems) != null ? MyMethodReturningObject(x.SubItems): x.SubItems[0])
```

But without calling the method twice.

Is this possible via Linq?

Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
var test = myListOfItems.Select(x => MyFunctionReturningObject(x.SubItems) ?? x.SubItems[0])
```

Comment: Yes this does work to check if an object is null! Thank you very much!